# Asking abount Finite element interpolation

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

At first, sorry if my question is a stupid thing. It is about mapping a function into semi-discrete space. Let's see, for the basis function $\{\phi_i(x)\}_{i = 1}^n $, the projection of function $u(x,t)$ in semi-discrete space is
$$ u_h(x,t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i(t)\phi_i(x).$$
If we want to construct the projection of $u^2$, we should construct it like this
$$ u^2_h(x,t) = \sum_{i = 1}^n u_i^2(t)\phi_i(x)$$
or this:
$$ u^2_h(x,t) = \bigg(\sum_{i = 1}^n u_i(t)\phi_i(x)\bigg)^2.$$

Comment: The first formula is the right one. Anyway, as $u$ seems to be a linear combination of the basis function, $u^2$ has no reason to be so and performing this projection seems weird.

Comment: How is the first one correct?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Both approaches to get an approximation of $u^2$ are fine. For the first one, $u_h^2(t)$ is an element in the FE space for all $t$, which is not true for the second one. To decide which one is better, you need to specify what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you! for all comments here. The purpose of this question is that I want to implement the Allen-Cahn equation ( $u_t-u_{xx} +u^3 -u =0$) using finite element method. So I confuse about the approximation of nonlinear term.